# Facebook SignIn not working in Firefox due to CSP error

Tags: facebook, firefox, nginx, flask

I've developed an app in Python Flask and deployed it with Nginx and uWSGI. 
On login page in Firefox Facebook login button is not showing and I get an warning message in console:

`Content Security Policy: Ignoring “'unsafe-inline'” within script-src: ‘strict-dynamic’ specified`

`Content Security Policy: Ignoring “https:” within script-src: ‘strict-dynamic’ specified`

`Content Security Policy: Ignoring “http:” within script-src: ‘strict-dynamic’ specified`

I've tried setting CSP config on nginx and in flask using [Flask-CSP](https://github.com/twaldear/flask-csp) but the problem is still here.

Facebook SignIn works on all other browsers and Google Sign in works in all browsers including Firefox.